# createSelector - I'm doing it wrong

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I thought this was right, but it doesn't work:

```
  selectClaimTypeById: ((any) => MemoizedSelector<any, ClaimType[]>) = (props: any) => createSelector (
    this.claimtypeSelector,
    (claimTypes: ClaimType[]) => claimTypes
      .filter ((claimType: ClaimType) => (claimType.claimType === props.claimType)
      ))
```

***select(this.claimtypeSelector)*** correctly returns an array of ClaimTypes.  I THOUGHT the code above when called as ***select(selectClaimTypeById, {claimId: id})***, would return a filtered array of one claimType.

It returns a memoized function

```
this.store
  .pipe (
    select (this.selectors.selectClaimTypeById, {claimType: id}),
    take (1))
  .subscribe (data => record = data);
```

record = function memoized

I'm obviously missed something

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is defined as a function, so you have to invoke it:

```
this.store
  .pipe (
    select (this.selectors.selectClaimTypeById(id)),
    take (1))
  .subscribe (data => record = data);
```

For more examples and an explanation see [Parameterized selectors](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/parameterized-selectors)

Comment: DOH!   and I knew that when I wrote, but I shelved this for a couple of weeks and forgot by the time I got back to it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a method that returns a selector with:

```
selectClaimTypeById: ... = (props: any) => createSelector(
```

This should be probably just like this:

```
selectClaimTypeById: ... = createSelector(
```

This is your use-case in docs: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-with-props

Comment: I couldn't get Typescript to accept this approach, so I took the one above

Comment: What RxJS and NgRx versions you have?